# How can I separate NextJS App DIR root Layout from account layout?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to build a NextJS (APP ROUTING) web application with 2 sections:

1. Website
2. Account

I would like users to access the restricted account section via domain.tld/account whereas the website lives in domain.tld

ISSUE:
There is a navbar component declared in the root layout as follows:

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={poppins.className}>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

All page components in the app dir are sharing the above layout.
And here is my /account page component:

```
export default async function Account() {
  return (
    <>
      <p>My Account</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

This returns the web navbar component which I do not want in the account section.
How can I separate the root layout as web and have a different child layout for account or admin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to display your navbar for all paths but the `/account` route and its children. Picking the right one depends on the rest of your structure.

1. Generally speaking you can remove the `<Navbar />` from the root layout and place it in say `/foo/layout.tsx` instead to make sure only `/foo` and all child routes show the navbar while `/account` does not.
2. Otherwise, especially when it's a distinction at root level, you have to use so called [route groups](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups) which are a logical separation of folders and paths that does not affect routing directly. Route groups are denoted by folders whose names look like `(groupname)`. In your case you'd declare the following structure:

```
app/
├─ (group1)/
│  ├─ account/
│  │  ├─ page.tsx
│  ├─ layout.tsx
├─ (group2)/
│  ├─ page.tsx
│  ├─ layout.tsx
├─ layout.tsx
```

In this example you'd still have a root layout at `app/layout.tsx` that defines the root layout for all paths while at the same time being able to add your `<Navbar />` to `app/(group1)/layout.tsx` (name group as you see fit) which will only apply to all paths within the `(group1)` route group including the `/account` path.

I haven't tested it, but if your `(group1)` would only contain the `/account` route I think you could even simplify it as follows:

```
app/
├─ account/
│  ├─ page.tsx
│  ├─ layout.tsx
├─ (main)/
│  ├─ page.tsx
│  ├─ layout.tsx
├─ layout.tsx
```

Comment: [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-multiple-root)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Second option works for me.

Comment: @LexacleTechnologies Great! Please make sure to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark if it has completely solved your problem.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic of course. It's done. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

i did this in my nextjs app to and it works

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

export default function App({Component,pageProps: { session, ...pageProps }}) {

  const router = useRouter()


  if (router.pathname.includes('/account')) { //if the pathname include account no layout 
    return (
      <SessionProvider session={session}>
            <Component {...pageProps} theme={useTheme}/>
      </SessionProvider>
    )
  }

  return ( //here there is layout 
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
        <Layout setThemeChanged={setThemeChanged}> 
            <Component {...pageProps} theme={useTheme} />
        </Layout>
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```